# MATLAB GUI - Button Press returning error

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a simple MATLAB GUI Code, find attached. All it does is when a button is pressed it runs a function.

However when I press this button twice, it is throwing an error

> Undefined function 'GUI' for input arguments of type 'struct'.
>
> Error in @(hObject,eventdata)GUI('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
 set(handles.pushbutton1, 'enable','off'); 
 output = randomFunction(); 
    a = 1

while(1)
   a = a+1
    if a == 4 
        break; 
    end

end
set(handles.pushbutton1, 'enable','on');
```

Comment: Does `randomFunction` change your current working directory?

Comment: Good call, It does, but I am planning on making this as a standalone GUI in future, how would I work on that avenue. THe random function. actually asks the user to choose a directory, because it works on images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `randomFunction` must either change the current working directory or modify your `PATH` such that the GUI function (`GUI.m`) is no longer on the path and able to be found when you click the button the second time.

If you'd like to stop this behavior you have two options

1. The *preferred* option would be to modify `randomFunction` to *not* make this modification. A function should always the user's environment to the way that it was before being called. You can easily do this by using [`onCleanup`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) within `randomFunction`

   ```
   function randomFunction()
       folder = pwd;
       cleanup = onCleanup(@()cd(folder));

       % Normal contents of randomFunction
   end
   ```

   The other option within `randomFunction` though is to never use `cd`. This is the best practice. You can use full file paths instead to access files

   ```
   filename = fullfile(folder, 'image.png');
   imread(filename)
   ```
2. If you can't modify `randomFunction` you can modify your callback to remember what the current directory was before calling the function and then change it back after `randomFunction` completes. I would  actually recommend using `onCleanup` to do this to ensure that the directory is changed back even if `randomFunction` errors out

   ```
   function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
       set(handles.pushbutton1, 'enable', 'off'); 

       % Make sure that when this function ends we change back to the current folder
       folder = pwd;
       cleanup = onCleanup(@()cd(folder));

       output = randomFunction(); 
       a = 1

       while(1)
          a = a+1
           if a == 4 
               break; 
           end

       end
       set(handles.pushbutton1, 'enable','on');
   ```

Comment: The random function choses a folder, where there are set of images and does image processing on them. When this folder is choosen, it also reads a matlab function in this folder. How would I make this GUI a standalone?

Comment: @JeshKundem See my update about how to use full filepaths.